# SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to add some JavaScript functions to a page with SSRS.  I'm using jQuery to determine if the document is loaded.  The problem I'm having is that SSRS continues to load, but the jQuery load event triggers before SSRS loading.  Does anyone know any SSRS JavaScript events that would allow me to determine if SSRS has finished loading?  Or should I add a jQuery load event to the report element?

Comment: do you mean 'ssrs' is a javascript file you're loading ?

Comment: @GuillaumeCisco with ssrs he means SQL Server Reporting Services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the method I need here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756413.aspx